# How Does The GTK Library Connect to Gnome Windows Manager

Tags: linux, user-interface, gtk, dbus, gdm

I was reading an article on the X Window Server. How Does The GTK Library Connect to Gnome Windows Manager? Is it through a Unix Domain Socket or through DBus or through some other inter process communication (IPC) mechanism?

Thanks.

Comment: The gnome window manager is typically built using gtk as a shared library. It might conceivable be built statically.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an X11 system then it's directly calling XCB or Xlib.